# Expected value and variance of n independent links

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A chain is made by connecting n links. The lengths of different links are independent and uniform over [50,70] millimeters. What is the expected value and variance of the length of a chain obtained by connecting n links?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The joint pdf is

$$
f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)=f(x_1)f(x_2)\cdots f(x_n)=[f(x)]^n
$$
where $x\sim U(50, 70)$. Let $X=x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$. The expectation can then easily be derived from E(X) and considering the independence the variance is just as straight-forward. Good luck!

Comment: The expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations even if the random variables are not independent. However, independence is used here in concluding that the variance of a sum is the sum of variances.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Oh, of course. Clarified that part. Thanks.